# Programmatically hide and close the window of current NSViewController

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I would like to hide/close my main app window in `func viewDidLoad()` and only show/unhide the main window if some event requires it.

I tried `self.view.window?.close()` but this leaves a white window. I also tried `NSApp.hide(nil)` but then I can't unhide with `NSApp.unhide(nil)`. Here is some sample code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   NSApp.hide(nil)
   runTest()
}

func runTest () {
   let check = false

   if check == false {
      NSApp.unhide(nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Uncheck "Visible At Launch" in IB if you want to window to be invisible by default.

Comment: window.setIsVisible

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion El Tomato but is still doesent work. there must be a simple solution to: starting the app hidden and unhide if something happens without killing the window completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide the initial window on start with OS X storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999177/how-to-hide-the-initial-window-on-start-with-os-x-storyboards)

Answer (score 2):

From the [NSWindow documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow)

> `func orderOut(_ sender: Any?)`
>
> Removes the window from the screen list, which hides the window.
>
> `func makeKeyAndOrderFront(_ sender: Any?)`
>
> Moves the window to the front of the screen list, within its level, and makes it the key window; that is, it shows the window.

`Hide` and `Close` are two different things:

> If the window is the key or main window, the window object immediately behind it is made key or main in its place. Calling `orderOut(_:)` causes the window to be removed from the screen, but does not cause it to be released. See the [`close()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419662-close) method for information on when a window is released. Calling `orderOut(_:)` on a child window causes the window to be removed from its parent window before being removed.

Hiding the application (`NSApp.hide(nil`) is another different thing: It

> Hides all the receiver’s windows, and the next app in line is activated.

Comment: I read this but I didn't know how to use it. Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Just call the methods on the main window e.g.  `self.view.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)`

Comment: I tried `self.view.window?.orderOut(nil)` in `func viewDidLoad()`. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: try `orderOut(self)`

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad(); self.view.window?.orderOut(self);}` doesn't work either.